# Is it possible to create a filtered index comparing two columns to each other?

Tags: sql-server

Trying to create a filtered index, and getting the error:

> Incorrect WHERE clause for filtered index 'ix_test123' on table 'test123'.

```
create table test123(a int, b int, v varchar(100))

-- drop index ix_test123 on test123

create unique index ix_test123 on test123(v)
where (a = b)
```

Essentially I want to create a unique constraint on column 'v', when columns 'a' and 'b' are equal. Is that possible?  Went through limitations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16, but don't see how they apply to this scenario.

Comment: `(a = b)` isn't a valid clause for the `WHERE`; though not specified in the limitations (that I can see), you can't have 2 different columns on both sides of the boolean expression.

Comment: There might be an indirect way of doing it using a computed column or a schemabound view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a filtered index comparing two columns to
> each other?

No.

Filtered indexes [only allow conditions of the form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax-for-sql-server-azure-sql-database-azure-sql-managed-instance) `column_name <comparison_op> constant` / or `column_name IN (constant ,...n)`.

Additionally you can't create a filtered index on a computed column.

You can use an indexed view for this. It is valid to create a schemabound view with query

```
create or alter view ViewTest123
with schemabinding
as
select t.v
from dbo.test123 t
where t.a = t.b;
```

and then create a unique clustered index on the view.

```
create unique clustered index ix_test123 on ViewTest123 (v);
```